# How to correctly calculate time remaining from php date time

Tags: php

The expiry date is in unix timestamp approx 30th sept 2020 6AM

```
$expiry_date_time = 160142766; //30 sept 2020 6AM
$dt1 = new DateTime();
$dt1->setTimestamp($expiry_date_time);
$now = new DateTime();
$i = $now->diff($dt1);
$time_remaining = $i->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes');
echo $time_remaining;
```

Output today when i ran the code (11th OCT 2020)

```
0 years 0 months 11 days 7 hours 19 minutes
```

This code doesn't give incorrect result but it cannot differentiate between expired and not expired, like in the above case the subscription had expired it gives the output 11 days which is not entirely incorrect because it has been 11 days since its expired if you calculate but shouldn't it be Negative 11 days ?
If I make the expiry date to two days in the future it will correctly calculate and output 2 days, xx hours and xx minutes.
How to make it differentiate between expired and not expired ?

Comment: You can compare the `expired DateTime` and `current DateTime` for checking whether it is expired or not

Answer (score 1):

`DateInterval` has an [`invert`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.invert) flag for this very purpose:

> `invert`
>
> Is 1 if the interval represents a negative time period and 0 otherwise.

```
$expiry_date_time = 160142766; //30 sept 2020 6AM
$dt1 = new DateTime();
$dt1->setTimestamp($expiry_date_time);
$now = new DateTime();

// What you're doing right now
$i = $now->diff($dt1);
var_dump($i->invert);  // int(1)

// If you're doing it the other way around
$i = $dt1->diff($now);
var_dump($i->invert);  // int(0)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fbQ9P)**

Answer (score 0):

```php
$expiry_date_time = 160142766; //30 sept 2020 6AM
$dt1 = new DateTime();
$dt1->setTimestamp($expiry_date_time);
$now = new DateTime();
$i = $now->diff($dt1);
$time_remaining = $i->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes');
if($expiry_date_time - $now()->getTimestamp() < 0) {
    $time_remaining = "expired $time_remaining ago";
}
echo $time_remaining;
```

This will add some text to the text if it is in the past, to make sure you know if it is expired or not yet.